# Are there any plugins that allow commenting on Blogs?

Tags: comments, blogs, social-networking

I am busy researching the best solution to us to apply comments to my blog.

I know that there are a number of interesting solutions such as **Facebook Comments**

Basically I would like to hear opinions around what the best solution would be to accomodate the following requirements:

1. You should be able to comment using Facebook
2. If you dont have facebook you should also be able to comment as Anonymous
3. You should also be able to comment using your Yahoo, Gmail and Hotmail IDs
4. Commenting should trigger email notifications
5. When someone replies to your comment or thread it should also give you an email notification

Interested to see what else is out there in terms of a solution other than Facebook comments

Thanks in advance.

Wez

Comment: done - would be nice to see a company provide more of a analytic driven service, which includes sentiment analysis on the commenting for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend [disqus](http://disqus.com/). It's used in lots of places and works well with my own blog(s). It allows for the user to authentic (optional) from several openID providers (google, facebook). In fact, it looks like it meets all of your requirements

Comment: Very nice, I however preferred Wildfyre as they offered the same functionality, just with slightliy better config and setup. Both of these services are pretty pricey though...

Comment: I'll have to check `Wildfyre` out. Pricey? Disqus is free unless you want the [add-ons](http://disqus.com/admin/addons/packages/)

Comment: apologies, its actually LiveFyre - http://www.livefyre.com/ the main feature I am looking for is custom "From Email" addresses...........its a bit confusing for a customer if he comments on your portal and gets an email from Disqus....

Comment: as Disqus is used on a large number of sites I, IMHO, don't see this a problem. They have likely have received an email from Disqus before if they have notifications turned on. Engadget uses Disqus and I get emails from Disqus rather then Engadget of a reply to my comment.